# Refreshing a view page refreshes controller also codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Controller :

```
public function new_question($question_title)
{
if($this->db->insert('question',$data))
  {
  $data['asked_title'] = $decoded_question_title;    
  $data['max_id'] = $this->db->insert_id();          
  $this->load->vars($this->data);
  $this->load->view('new_question',$data);
  } 
}
```

Friends in the above code I'm trying to insert the values into the database . If the insert has been successful then the controller should load the new_question (View) and the $data will be passed to next page. Every thing works fine i.e(insertion of values and passing of data to view ). my problem is if i try to refresh my  new_question page(view page) . the controller($this->db->insert('question',$data)) ) has been called again and the inserting of same values takes place again . so I dont know why it happens also guide me how to prevent the refreshing of controller while refreshing the view .

Comment: Once complete insert process, then redirect to another function in controller

Comment: before to insert the value check the value is inserted or not, if not insert then insert it otherwise fetch the value

Answer (score 0):

As Vaira suggested, you should redirect to another page (one for new and another for save purpose). As if you stay in the same page, post data will be available in that and refreshing a page will post it again and do all the listed operation.

Another way to put some condition using variable and check if that specific variable is having value to ignore insertion of same data. Or may be duplicate checking in db would also help.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm....

```
public function new_question($question_title)
{
    if($this->db->insert('question', $data))
    {
        $question_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        // reset post data with redirect
        redirect(site_url('your_controller/view_question/' . $question_id));
    } 
}

public function view_question($question_id = 0)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('your_questions_table', array('id' => $question_id), 1);

    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        $this->load->view('your_question_view', array('question' => $query->row()));
    }
    else
    {
        // question not fount
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a problem in you business logic. You don't check if the value has already been inserted. You either have to do the check or redirect to another page.

```
public function new_question($question_title)
{
  if(!isset($this->sessions->inserted) || !$this->sessions->inserted)
  {
    $inserted = $this->db->insert('question',$data)
    if (înserted)
    {
      $data['asked_title'] = $decoded_question_title;    
      $data['max_id'] = $this->db->insert_id();          
      $this->load->vars($this->data);
      $this->load->view('new_question',$data);
    }
    // don't forget to deleted this session data when the program ends 
    $this->sessions->set_userdata('inserted', $inserted);   
  } 
}
```